# Reading multiple URLs from a text file, processing each web page, and scraping the content inside

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, python-requests

I have a .txt file with a list of multiple URLs. My purpose is to open this .txt file, access each URL in each line, scrape the content inside each URL, and append the content with list of multiple URLs in the txt file to the "draft.csv" file.

When I tried to run other codes, the recommended request result shows "Please turn on JavaScript and refresh the page", so I intended to use Selenium instead to get this resolved. I am able to fetch all the pages as wanted, but unable to see the desired content in each link.

Below is list of multiple URLs for example:

```
http://example.com/2267/15175/index.html
http://example.com/2267/16796/index.html
http://example.com/2267/17895/index.html
```

This is my current code using Selenium and Requests.

```
from lxml import etree
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import sys
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import requests

frame =[]

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options)

with open("draft.txt", "r") as file:
  for line in file:
    url = line.rstrip("\n")
    print(url)

    driver.get(url)
    html = etree.HTML(driver.page_source)
    allurl = requests.get(url)
    htmltext = allurl.text

    extract_link = html.xpath('//span[@id="my_two"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]')
    for i in extract_link:
      link = i.xpath('./tbody/tr/td/div/p/a/@href')
      content = 'http://example.com'+ link[0]

      frame.append({
        'content': content,
        })

dfs = pd.DataFrame(frame)
dfs.to_csv('draft.csv',index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Thank you in advance for helping me with this!

Comment: your intention is to go through each url with its subs urls, or just enter each url of the file and extract its information?

Comment: @Dandal The content of each url is actually one or more sub url(s). So I would like to scrape that sub links from the list of multiple urls I got from the txt file. Hope you could help me with this. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must load selenium inside a for loop, and you can use bs4 for scraping:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open("urls.txt")
urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
For url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    ...
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    Information = soup.find('title')
    Url = url
    ...
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks @Dandal. I've amended a bit of your suggested code and it's working like a charm now. Have a great day to you!